# How do I add a new region using roslyn (CodeFixProvider)

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I want to add a new `#region` to my code using a CodeFixProvider.
I already know that regions are part of the leading trivia of a node.

But how can I create a new `RegionDirectiveTrivia`?

Comment: Serious question, why would you want to add regions? Regions are widely recognised as an anti-pattern, eg http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/53114/105684

Comment: Good hint. But for now regions are part of our corporate coding guidelines. I take this hint into the next meeting but for now this guideline is " a rule".

Comment: @David you didn't read that article right... as long as it is, another individual also stated that regions are not anti-patterns "regions can't really be an "anti-pattern" as that term is commonly used to describe program logic/design patterns, not the layout of a text editor" - just because one person makes the comment doesn't make it gospel.  The use of regions is very subjective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `SyntaxFactory.RegionDirectiveTrivia()`. You can always refer to the [Roslyn Quoter](http://roslynquoter.azurewebsites.net/) site, when you don't know who to generate some part of a piece of code.

Comment: Thanks. Found following possibility:

`SyntaxFactory.Trivia(SyntaxFactory.RegionDirectiveTrivia( true).WithHashToken(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.HashToken))
.WithRegionKeyword(SyntaxFactory.Token( SyntaxKind.RegionKeyword))
.WithEndOfDirectiveToken(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxFactory.TriviaList(SyntaxFactory.PreprocessingMessage(@"myTest")),  SyntaxKind.EndOfDirectiveToken,SyntaxFactory.TriviaList()) ))`